# filling in textfield by id javascript

Tags: javascript, button, textbox

I have code that has a text field and a button made in javascript. When the user clicks the button, it opens up a new window to a website's search page. What I wanted to do was to fill in the search field by using it's id and then activate the website's search button. I haven't seem to be able to get the text passed to the external site's textfield but here's what I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function mySearch()
{


popupWindow = window.open(

'http://www.websitehere.com','popUpWindow','height=768,width=1024,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')


popupWindow.focus();

popupWindow.searchpath1 = 'test value';


}
// ]]></script>
<center><form><input name="searchTxt" type="text" /><br />&nbsp; <input onclick="mySearch()" value="Search" type="button" /></form></center>
```

textBoxId would be the id of the search textbox on the newly opened window.

If anything doesn't make sense, let me know.

here is the source code for the textbox of the external site:

```
 <input title="Search Term" type="text" name="searchpath1" id="searchpath1" maxlength="255" size="25" style="width: 300px;" value=""/>
```

Comment: Are both your website and the popup source in the same domain?

Comment: @PSCoder  no, the popup window is an external site

Comment: Hm. Maybe, you can't do that if it's another domain.

Comment: @apast that's what i'm thinking. I just made a local copy of the site and it worked fine.

Comment: @apast are there any other ways of filling in a textbox? I originally was hoping it would be like google so I could just pass the search terms in to the url but it doesn't take any parameters

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
popupWindow.document.getElementById('textBoxId').value = 'test value';
```

instead of

```
popupWindow.textBoxId = 'test value';
```

Comment: i've tried many variations of this..it just doesnt seem to have any effect at all. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: i think its impossible then :)

Comment: aww bummer. i really thought this would be really neat! Ah well

Comment: i think this could work if the newly opened page is one the same domain. but editing the page on other server would be a real security problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the input text DOM element 'textBoxId' and set 'value' property of this obtained element.

This line is wrong

```
popupWindow.textBoxId = 'test value';
```

Use following lines to replace it:

```
var targetTextField = popupWindow.document.getElementById('textBoxId');
targetTextField.value = "test value";
```

Here, I rewrote full function definition to evaluate proposed solution. Try it and let us know how it worked! []s

```
function mySearch()
{
    popupWindow = window.open('file:///tmp/form.html','popUpWindow','height=768,width=1024,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')

    if (window.focus()) 
        popupWindow.focus();

    var targetTextField = popupWindow.document.getElementById('textBoxId');
    targetTextField.value = 'test value';
    targetTextField.focus();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, I tried it but it didnt seem to fill the field. It seems like the javascript code stops after it opens the new window. I'll attach the code that i got from the source code of the site (I would just give you the link but its only accessible locally on the network